# SQL query syntax error where the syntax appears to be correct

Tags: mysql

I dont know what is the problem with this query. It seems very fine to me.

```
select o.id, p.date, u.billingName, u.billingPhone, u.billingCompany,
       u.billingAddress, u.billingCity, u.billingState, u.billingCountry,
       u.billingZip, u.shippingName, u.shippingPhone, u.shippingCompany,
       u.shippingAddress, u.shippingCity, u.shippingState, u.shippingCountry,
       u.shippingZip, o.layer, o.boardSizeWidth,o.boardSizeHeight, o.quantity
from order o, purchase p, useraccount u
where p.id = 1 and o.id = p.OrderId and u.id = p.UserId
```

> Error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o, purchase p, useraccount u where p.id = 1 and o.id = p.OrderId and u.id ' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword. It must be escape using backtick.

```
....FROM `Order` o
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have a chance to alter the identifier, change the table name which is not present on the reserved keyword list. This will avoid you from future headache.

Comment: two downvotes? what's wrong with this? It seems I'm getting downvotes every day for no reason.

Comment: Wasn't me; but why do you care if you have 84.2k?

Comment: Wasn't me, but I received one too.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I know. I didn't tell it was you. Do you know what downvotes really means? asides from deducting two rep points?

Comment: my impression is that it means that there's another answer available that's superior to the one being downvoted thus creating a clear differentiation between the two

Comment: @JW I know what the Stack definition is. But you forget there are humans with these input devices called mice and they don't care.

Comment: @swasheck I guess you right. bluefeets's answer is very good because it shows another point for using ANSI join, but is it really a reason to have a downvote for not showing it? I guess the main point of the question is what causes the error in the query right?

Answer (score 4):

The table `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) an needs to be escaped using backticks.

Also you should use standard ANSI JOIN syntax when joining your tables.  See below for how this will be done.

```
select ....
from `order` o
inner join purchase p
    on o.id = p.OrderId
inner join useraccount u 
    on u.id = p.UserId
where p.id = 1
```

As a side note, you should avoid using reserved words for table and column names.

Comment: +1 over the other answer for actually taking the time to use the OP query and show the ANSI join syntax.